# C++ - Read from file to double

Tags: c++, readfile

I'm relatively new to programming and taking a course in C++ currently. I haven't had any major problems so far. I am making a program where an X amount judges can score 0.0 - 10.0 (double) and then the highest and lowest one is removed then an average is calculated and printed out.

This part is done, now I want to read from a file in the shape of:
example.txt - 
10.0
9.5
6.4
3.4
7.5

But I am stumbling onto problems with the dot (.) and how to get around it to get the number into a double. Any suggestions and (good) explanations so I can understand it?

---

**TL;DR: Reading from file (E.G. '9.7') to a double variable to put into an array.**

Comment: Got any code for what you're trying and currently struggling with?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16718146/777186) will work if you replace `int` with `double` there.

Comment: Have you tried `operator>>` for type `double`?

Comment: There must be 100 other questions exactly the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your **textfile is whitespace delimited**, you can use that to your advantage by utilizing `std::istream` objects who skip whitespace by default (in this case, `std::fstream`):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifile("example.txt", std::ios::in);
    std::vector<double> scores;

    //check to see that the file was opened correctly:
    if (!ifile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "There was a problem opening the input file!\n";
        exit(1);//exit or do additional error checking
    }

    double num = 0.0;
    //keep storing values from the text file so long as data exists:
    while (ifile >> num) {
        scores.push_back(num);
    }

    //verify that the scores were stored correctly:
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << scores[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note:

It is highly recommended to use `vectors` in lieu of dynamic arrays where possible for a myriad number of reasons as discussed here:

[When to use vectors and when to use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865861/when-to-use-vectors-and-when-to-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream fin("num.txt");
    double d;
    fin >> d;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

Does that do what you want?

Comment: Your version only reads *one* double number. And, it is stored in a *variable* and *not* an array (as the OP stated).

Comment: @jrd1 concur with both things you mentioned, but the point was to help with the main concept he was struggling with, which I interpreted as reading in doubles because of the decimal point. I find there is nothing quite like experience when learning. If I'm given too much right off the bat, I tend to not learn as deeply. Oh well. YMMV. :-)